# How to use pathlib for a nas drive path in python

Tags: python, csv, text, pathlib, nas

There are files in nas drive and i want find the files and iterate each file.below is variable i m declaring
pathx = path.Path('////NAS01042pn/data/FILESHARE/Jobs/ASM_File/Inbound/NONPROD/AWE_Test')

```
for path in os.scandir(pathx):
if path.is_file():
    print(path.name)
    filename = path.name
    if('ASM_Test_MEMBERS_' in path.name):
    if(True):
        fileListCheck = path.name.split('_')
        lastString = fileListCheck[-1]
        firstLastStringList = lastString.split('.')
```

but if i do like this i get error as the mentioned path doesnt exist. Also tried below method-
#pathx = b'\\NAS01042pn\data\OPTUM_HC_FILESHARE\Talend_Job_Conductor\ASM_Operations\Inbound\NONPROD\Test'
but here it stores as bytes and i get error as firstLastStringList cannot be bytes.
Any suggestions how to use pathlib for nas drive.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me from a windows machine.
I changed forward slash to backward slash with escape:

```
import path as path

pathx = path.Path('\\\\NAS01042pn\\data\\FILESHARE\\Jobs\\ASM_File\\Inbound\\NONPROD\\AWE_Test')
```

Comment: i tried ur code but getting invalid syntax error.. Tried both forward and backward both i m getting syntax error. pathx = path.Path'////NAS01042pn/data/FILESHARE/Jobs/ASM_File/Inbound/NONPROD/AWE_Test' and pathx = path.Path'\\\\NAS01042pn\data\FILESHARE\Jobs\ASM_File\Inbound\NONPROD\AWE_Test'

Comment: are you able to access the shared location path from Windows explorer?

Comment: yes Iam able to access from windows.